Alternative definition of derivative in real analysis
I am working on the following definition of derivative.
Let $I$ be an open interval and $f \colon I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function, and let $x \in I.$ The function $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if and only if $\exists$ $f^{\prime}(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ and a function $r \colon I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$\lim_{y \rightarrow x} \dfrac{r(y)}{y-x}=0$$ such that for all $y \in I$,$$f(y)=f^{\prime}(x)(y-x)+f(x)+r(y).$$
I understand the definition very well. But I have the following question.
Why is the condition $\lim_{y \rightarrow x} \dfrac{r(y)}{y-x}=0$ needed? Can you convince me that why the condition $\lim_{y \rightarrow x} r(y)=0$ is not sufficient? I know that the first condition is stronger, but I was wondering why the second one is not good enough.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Using the weaker definition, every continuous function would be differentiable, with an arbitrary value for $f'(x)$.

With the weaker condition, derivatives are no longer unique. For any $c \in \Bbb R$, we would also have
$$
f(y) = f'(x) + c + f(x) + [r(y) - c(y-x)],
$$
and $r(y) + c(y-x)$ approaches $0$ as $y \to x$.

Intuitively, in order for $f(y) \approx L(y) = f(x) + f'(x)(y-x)$ to be the best possible linear approximation of $f$, the remainder $r(y) = f(y) - L(y)$ must go to zero faster than linear functions

The idea comes from the fact that your definition is equivalent to the limit
$$f'(x)=\lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$
existing; indeed rearranging your equation we have
$$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}-\frac{r(y)}{y-x}=f'(x),$$
so what we wish for is for the second term to vanish, which is precisely when $\frac{r(y)}{y-x}\to0$ as $y\to x$. But now why is it not enough that $r(y)\to0$ as $y\to x$? Well let us try to construct a counterexample by first finding some function $r$ with $r(y)\to0$ but $\frac{r(y)}{y-x}\not\to0$ as $y\to x$. The easiest example would be to take $r(y)=y-x$. Consider now the constant function
$$f(x)=0$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Then clearly
$$f(y)=-1\cdot(y-x)+f(x)+r(y)$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$. So if this was our definition, then this would imply that $f'(x)=1$ for all $y\in\mathbb R$, which clearly is not what we want. But it gets even worse, as you also have that
$$f(y)=\alpha\cdot(y-x)+f(x)-\alpha\cdot r(y),$$
for any $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. But this would imply that $f'(x)=\alpha$ for any $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. So the derivative is not even unique anymore, and any constant function can have any real number as a derivative! As you can hopefully see by these examples, if we only require that
$$\lim_{y\to x}r(y)=0$$
and not that
$$\lim_{y\to x}\frac{r(y)}{y-x}=0,$$
then we start losing a lot of important properties of the derivatives, such as uniqueness, and the definition is no longer really useful.
